# Breeze with a Unit Of Work/Repository pattern

Tags: breeze, single-page-application

I was just wondering how I should go about implementing breeze's **EFContextProvider** in a separate data layer project. Also, since that project is a class library and not an MVC 4 application, how should I include this into my project? I don't really need the whole bag of tricks that is in the Breeze NuGet package, just **EFContextProvider** stuff. I want to implement a Unit of work pattern using the **EFContextProvider** DbContext wrapper, like John Papa has done in his wonderful pluralsight course. Has anyone done this yet? any tips?

Thanks

Comment: Just looking into the guts of breeze and found the EF wrapper inside the Breeze.WebApi dll, I want those parts, in my class library, without any of the other jazz. Do these depend on anything that is MVC 4 specific? Maybe I could just put the dll in there and only use the EF parts of it?

Comment: Ward has published out this link as guidance on the repo patter http://www.breezejs.com/spa-template#server Looking more into how to include breeze into my separate class libraries now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We've got a more sophisticated sample coming called "TempHire" that has a full blown UoW with Repos and separate model projects.

Breeze.NET components (the .NET server-side helpers for a Breeze app ... if you're going with .NET) are all in a single .DLL They have no dependence on MVC at all ... zip. There is Web API stuff in there. Maybe that's what concerns you. Well ... remember that this is [open source on GitHub](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze). You are not constrained to the Breeze .DLL.  Build your own out of the parts you want.

In my view, the UoW is a short hop from Repository. If you understand what a bounded context is and can translate that to a DbContext implementation, I figure you shouldn't need much help making the transition yourself. There's no magic to it.

For everyone I highly recommend Scott Allen's videos on Repository and UOW in the [Pluralsight Design Patterns course](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=patterns-library) ... perhaps the clearest, jargon-free exposition of these patterns I've ever seen.

Comment: Thanks Ward, I'll look into that sample when it comes to see what you've done. As for now, I'm trying to build my own just so I can get a feel for everything (pretty new with the stuff and want to understand how it works)

Comment: Just starting to learn about SPAs and Breeze. I'm using Angular and was curious if there is a TempHire sample project in the works using Angular?

Comment: Not soon. But there is another sample coming (Zza) which uses Angular in a more sophisticated way than ToDo. It uses UoW for example.

Comment: Is the new sample on GitHub or somewhere I can take a look now as it progresses? So far I've used the TempHire example for server side and ready to move into Angular / Breeze.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a post from the Breeze folks about how to use a UoW and Repo on the server with Breeze 
http://www.breezejs.com/spa-template#server

Comment: Hey John, yea I've seen that. At this point, I'm more interested in how I can layer this out into a separate class library project (like you have done in your plural sight courses) without including all of the extra MVC stuff the Breeze dll includes. I only care because nuget tells me I need to be an MVC project to include this file, when I only want the data part.

Comment: Install HotTowelette NuGet package. It has breeze, asp.net but no MVC

Comment: Hi John... I see no mention of UoW in the link. Has it changed?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Its just Repo. I dont see a UoW example.

Comment: Yea, no UoW.. But with Odata, you get custom queries, so that takes care of a lot of things that I needed the Repo and UoW for anyway. The UoW would be pretty nice to dish out different Bounded DbContexts though. I don't like the fact that you have to NuGet the whole BreezeWebApi dll in you class library just for the EFContextProvider though, but I'm just being picky I guess.